# Batch Script for Check and Cleanup

Tags: batch-file, scripting

i want to write a batch script where i need to check if a directory is empty or not, if not empty i want to clean that particular directory. Path will passed via command line argument.

Comment: Why bother checking if the folder is empty first? Simply delete all files/folders each time. If the folder is already empty or does not exist, then the delete operation will be just as fast as checking if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example code to get you started:

```bat
@Echo Off
If "%~1"=="" GoTo :EOF
If Not Exist "%~1\" GoTo :EOF
Dir/B/A "%~1\*"|Find /V "">Nul&&Call :CleanIt
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:CleanIt
Rem Your clean command(s) here
```

*You should only need to add your specific code to the bottom*